# How to find the derivative of $f(x)=x^{4/3}$ at $x=0$ using the definition of derivatives?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> How to find the derivative of $f(x)=x^{4/3}$ at $x=0$ using the definition of derivatives?

---

I've tried to solve the problem myself which results to the expansion of $(x+h)^{4/3}$:
$$x^{4/3} + 4/3xh^{1/3} + 2x^{2/3}h^{2/3} + 4/3x^{1/3}h +h^{4/3}$$

But it seems not to be the correct answer.

Comment: Is your h small wrt x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{t\to x}{t^{4/3} -x^{4/3} \over t - x } = \lim_{t\to x} {(t^{4/3} -x^{4/3})(t^{8/3} + x^{4/3}t^{4/3} + x^{8/3}) \over (t - x)(t^{8/3} + x^{4/3}t^{4/3} + x^{8/3}) }= \lim_{t\to x} {{(t +  x)(t^2 + x^2)}\over t^{8/3} + x^{4/3}t^{4/3} + x^{8/3}}=4/3 x^{1/3}$$

Comment: You can fill in the details.

Answer (score 1):

You could proceed as follows using taylor expansion:

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x^{4/3}-(x+h)^{4/3}}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x^{4/3}-(x^{4/3}+\frac{4hx^{1/3}}{3}+\frac{2h^2}{9x^{2/3}}+O(h^3))}{h} $$

$$=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{4}{3}\cdot hx^{1/3}+\frac{2h^2}{9x^{2/3}}+O(h^3)}{h} =\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{4}{3}x^{1/3} +\frac{2h}{9x^{2/3}}+\frac{O(h^3)}{h}\right) =\frac{4}{3}x^{1/3}$$

Comment: he's probably trying to use the limit definition to compute the derivative of $x^\frac{4}{3}$

Comment: I'm trying to use the limit definition to solve $x^{2/3}$

Comment: @KendraYu Check the answer now.

Comment: Thanks, @mrnovice!

Comment: But the Taylor expansion uses the derivative!

Answer (score 1):

Both of the current answers show that the derivative of $f(x)=x^{4/3}$ is $f'(x)=\frac{4}{3}x^{1/3}$, and then evaluate the resulting expression at $x=0$, but this is not necessary to answer the question, and is almost certainly not what is intended.

Since all we want is to compute the derivative at $x=0$, we can simply write:

$$f'(0) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^{4/3}-0}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}h^{1/3}=0$$